# remove layers from ggplot chart with particular layers automatically

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to automatically remove the `geom_label` layers from a `ggplot` chart that have a particular label. My code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gginnards)

df <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=runif(100))

gp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_label(aes(x=20, y=-Inf, label="A"), vjust = -0.2) +
      geom_label(aes(x=40, y=-Inf, label="B"), vjust = -0.2) +
      geom_label(aes(x=60, y=-Inf, label="A"), vjust = -0.2) +
      geom_label(aes(x=80, y=-Inf, label="C"), vjust = -0.2)

print(gp)
```

I tried:

```
gp <- delete_layers(gp, match_type = "GeomLabel")
```

using the `gginnards` package, but then all `geom_labels` are removed. In this example I would like to automatically remove only the `geom_labels` from the ggplot chart that have label "A", for example with something like:

```
gp <- delete_layers(gp, match_type = "GeomLabel" & label = "A")
```

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Hi @Wilbert, I think you'll need to modify your question to get more help. In your example the way to delete the "A" labels would be to remove the two  `geom_label` lines that include "A", and I don't think this is what you are asking. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer that solves your specific question about removing the `geom_label` layers when the label is set to A. You can turn it into a function fairly easily.

The answer makes use of the `extract_layers` function to grab all the layers and find the corresponding labels for each `geom_label` layer. I then subset the result to get the indices of the labels when they equal "A". Finally I use the `idx` parameter (instead of the `match_type` parameter) of the `delete_layers` function to remove the target layers by their index.

Note that you cannot use both the `match_type` and the `idx` parameters at the same time in the `delete_layers` function.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gginnards)

set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = runif(100))

gp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_label(aes(x=20, y=-Inf, label="A"), vjust = -0.2) +
    geom_label(aes(x=40, y=-Inf, label="B"), vjust = -0.2) +
    geom_label(aes(x=60, y=-Inf, label="A"), vjust = -0.2) +
    geom_label(aes(x=80, y=-Inf, label="C"), vjust = -0.2)

print(gp)

# get the geomlabel layers
geom_label_layers <- extract_layers(gp, match_type = "GeomLabel")

# get the labels for each of the geomlabel layers 
labels_vals <- sapply(geom_label_layers, function(x) x$mapping$label)

# get the indices of the labels that equal "A", and then add 1 to them because the first layer is the geom_point() layer and we don't want to remove that
A_labels_idx <- which(labels_vals %in% "A") + 1

# delete the layers using the indices we just found
gp2 <- delete_layers(gp, idx = A_labels_idx)

print(gp2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider functional programming methods: `Reduce` and `Filter`. Specifically, generate the ggplots in the functional form using `Reduce` on a list of layers since `+` operator actually calls the undocumented method, `+.gg`, available as a triple-colon namespace. However, you need to separate the labels from non-label items. Here generates exactly same output as OP's.

```
plot_labels <- list(geom_label(aes(x=20, y=-Inf, label="A"), vjust = -0.2),
                    geom_label(aes(x=40, y=-Inf, label="B"), vjust = -0.2),
                    geom_label(aes(x=60, y=-Inf, label="A"), vjust = -0.2),
                    geom_label(aes(x=80, y=-Inf, label="C"), vjust = -0.2)
                )

layers <- list(ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)),
               geom_point(),
               plot_labels
          )

Reduce(ggplot2:::`+.gg`, layers)
```

[image: Original Plot Output]

Then, call `Filter` to remove unneeded layers without needing another package:

```
sub_layers <- Filter(function(l) l$mapping$label != "A", plot_labels)   

layers <- list(ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)),
               geom_point(),
               sub_layers
          )

Reduce(ggplot2:::`+.gg`, layers)
```

[image: Adjusted Plot Output]

Comment: Nice solution as well.